# Is it possible to make a global variable?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm wondering how to make a variable global when the variable's value is dependent on an action listener. in response to a comment I need to be able to use a variable and its value anywhere in my code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class example {
    public static String a;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(200, 200);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        f.add(p);
        final JTextField tf = new JTextField("write stuff");
        p.add(tf);
        tf.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                a = tf.getText();
                //How would I make this global?
            }
        });
        //and I would use it in this JLabel
        JLable l = new JLabel(a);
        p.add(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: `public static final`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider making it `final` would mean she can never change it. `public static` would be enough.

Comment: True enough. I missed the "variable" part.  `public static volatile` then.

Comment: If you donat want to change the value of the gloabl variable then **public static final** otherwise simply **public static**

Comment: this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Better yet, @luna , ask this question with the title 'How to set JComponent text from within actionListener?' or something like that

Comment: @SamDJava Swing in inherently multithreaded, `volatile` is required if the OP wants a **global** variable.

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson ... overkill. Maybe check the content of the question next time and edit the title or something.

Comment: I agree with @Jarrod - this is certainly a dupe of the question marked.

Comment: there is no such thing as `global` scope in Java, the sooner the newbies learn this the better.

Comment: @BoristheSpider , disagree...isn't it more about programming to the swing interface?

Comment: It's about exposing a variable `v` as `Global v` so that it can be accessed anywhere. Regardless of the intent, there is no `Global` in Java so that answer stands. `public static volatile` only gets you so far as Swing is highly asynchronous.

Comment: I agree with @ironicaldiction, I think luna deserve a different answer.

Comment: @BoristheSpider , okay, but I think the ignorance of OP caused him to make question about globals when really all he needed to do was call `setText()` of the `JLabel l` added to the frame, which just needed to be in the highest scope of main.  There was no need for the variable `a` (the supposed global) to begin with.

Comment: Unless OP actually wanted to know if it's possible to make a global, concurrent variable in java, in which case you're right.

Comment: @ironicaldiction as it currently stands this question looks like a dupe and quacks like a dupe. If you think this question deserves an answer in its own right, then you (or the OP, as you have under 2000 rep) need to edit to show its true intent. Currently, this question would never make it off of the reopen queue.

Comment: Yup @awtszs your correct, I need a different answer.

Comment: You need a different answer why?